# Connection readyState is set to readOnly

Tags: aws-lambda, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I have a lambda that does writing to an Amazon ElastiCache (Memcached) cluster every 3 minutes. But some executions are taking an exception

```
Connection readyState is set to readOnly
```

The lambda is using **Runtime Node.js 12.x.** The Amazon ElastiCache cluster is with **Memcached engine** and **engine version 1.6.6** and **Node Type cache.t2.micro** with only 1 node. I did a test using multiple nodes and we have the same problem.

*The endpoint used by the lambda is the cluster configuration endpoint and not the node endpoint.*

Any suggestions to solve ?
Thanks